# Why can't a lambda return a class object if the class has explicit constructors?

Tags: c++, lambda, factory, explicit

I came across this curio and don't understand why the use of explicit constructors would cause this to fail.

I was trying to generate and initialize objects from configuration data using lambdas.  I found that the lambda could only return a copy of the object if the object's class definition did not use explicit constructors.  This code sample is a simplistic example of what I found.

```
class foo {
public:
    explicit foo() : _a(0) {}
    explicit foo(int val): _a(val) {}
    explicit foo(const foo& o) : _a(o._a) {}
    explicit foo(foo&& o) : _a(std::move(o._a)) {}
    foo& operator()(const foo& rhs) { if (this != &rhs) { _a = rhs._a; } return *this; }
    foo& operator()(foo&& rhs) { _a = std::move(rhs._a); return *this; }
    int a() const { return _a; }
    void a(int val) { _a = val; }
private:
    int _a;
};

auto makeFoo = [](int val) -> foo { return foo(val); };
```

As written the sample code fails to compile with the following errors on the makeFoo line:

```
In static member function ‘static foo<lambda(int)>::_FUN(int)’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::foo(foo)’
```

However, if I remove the 'explicit' tags from the foo constructors, the code compiles just fine.

Can someone enlighten me as to why the constructors cannot be explicit in this lambda?

Comment: quite sure you would have the same error also not using a lambda, with a `normal` function

Comment: Yes, I just checked.  It has nothing to do with the lambda.  It's all about how the return value is assigned.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, review the documentation about the [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) keyword.

> Specifies that a constructor or conversion function (since C++11) is explicit, that is, it cannot be used for implicit conversions and copy-initialization.

Basically, the explicit copy constructor means that the copy constructor will not be called implicitly.

You don't need to define your copy/move constructor, the compiler will generate them for you. Same for the copy/move assignment. Just remove them and you will be fine.

```
class foo {
public:
    foo() = default;
    explicit foo(int val): _a(val) {}
    int a() const { return _a; }
    void a(int val) { _a = val; }
private:
    int _a{0};
};
```

Comment: I'm aware that the compiler will create the copy/move constructors for me.  That's not quite the issue I was asking about.  It's more of why the return value balks when the constructors are explicit.  I guess it didn't occur to me that the return value is still being _assigned_ even if there is a construction in that line of code, and explicit copy/move constructors prevent assignment.  So, in general, the copy/move constructors should not be explicit.  Initialization constructors could be.